# ¿Es posible enviar como valor de un checkbox true/false en vez de checked/not checked?

Tags: jquery

Quería saber si es posible modificar de alguna forma el valor que se envía de un checkbox al mandar un formulario. Llega siempre como `checked/not checked` pero quería que se enviase con `true/false`.

Esto es debido a que estoy utilizando una herramienta como HubSpot en el que la propiedad con la que sincroniza está así establecido.

He probado lo siguiente, pero me sigue llegando como checked/not checked:

```
$("#checkbox1").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).attr('value', 'true');
  } else {
    $(this).attr('value', 'false');
  }
  
  $('#checkbox-value').text($('#checkbox1').val());
});
```

He probado también esta opción:

```
$("#checkbox1").prop('checked', true);
```

Ninguna de las 2 me ha funcionado.

Comment: Pero que acción quieres realizar si se cumple la condición?, o para que necesitas el true o false?, tienes mas checkbox?.

Answer (score 0):

Solo captura el **val** en una variable después de cambiarlo, y con ese valor ejecutas tu acción, ejemplo:

```js
$(".checkbox").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).attr('value', 'true');
    var check = $(this).val();
    console.log(check);
  } else {
    $(this).attr('value', 'false');
    var check = $(this).val();
    console.log(check);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="checkbox" value="first_checkbox"> Este es mi primer checkbox
</label>
```

En este caso solo mostramos el valor por consola al marcar = true, al desmarcar = false. Dime si te sirbio.